# BeanIO - Disable padding or skip field if null when marshaling to fix width file

Tags: java, bean-io

I'm trying to write a fixed-width file using BeanIO library. Here's the record in question:

```
@Record
open class KeySegment(
    @Field(at = 0, length = 1, required = true) var recordType: String = "",
    @Field(at = 1, length = 6, required = true) var primaryCorpId: String = "",
    @Field(at = 7, length = 16, minOccurs = 0) var creditCardAcc: String? = null,
    @Field(at = 7, length = 8, minOccurs = 0) var companyId: String? = null,
    @Field(at = 15, length = 8, minOccurs = 0) var sublevelId: String? = null,
    @Field(at = 23, length = 8, required = true) var fileCreateDate: String = "",
    @Field(at = 31, length = 8) var sourceId: String = "",
    @Field(at = 39, length = 816) var filler: String = ""
)
```

Notice that `creditCardAcc` and `companyId + sublevelId` hold the same positions in the file. Depending on the use case, we either set `creditCardAcc` field or `companyId` and `sublevelId`. Now for my use case, I want to set `creditCardAcc`, but the problem is that `companyId` and `sublevelId` are padded with space and overwrite the `creditCardAcc` field even if they are set to `null`.

One solution is to pull those fields into two subclasses extending `KeySegment`, and marshal subclass instead. But, I was wondering if there's a better native solution that I can use to accomplish this. For example, is there a way to disable the padding if the field is null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable the padding when the field is `null`. The `padding` attribute has the following description [here](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#field)

> If padding is enabled, the required field attribute has some control
>   over the marshalling and unmarshalling of null values.
>
> When unmarshalling a field consisting of all spaces in a fixed length
>   stream, if required is false, the field is accepted regardless of the
>   padding character. If required is true, a required field validation
>   error is triggered. And when marshalling a null field value, if
>   required is false, the field text is formatted as spaces regardless of
>   the configured padding character.

The last sentence of the quote is exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that. This paragraph describes what happens when the field is null. The question was whether there's a way to circumvent that with BeanIO config in any way.

Comment: And the answer is no